# How to convert Int to decimal in Node-Red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I want to convert a decimal number to 16 bit binary from a register that node-red reads with modbus.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test bits at specific offsets then you should portably be using bitwise operators like & and |

If you want to visualise the binary output the use the by `toString(radix)` method where the radix should be 2.

E.g. in a function node assuming the value to cover is in the `msg.payload`

```
msg.paload = msg.payload.toString(2);
return msg;
```

Comment: for example i read the value 64 from the register. Using the function you gave me it returns the same value before the function. I need to make the value in a string of bits.

Comment: That implies that the input is a string not a number, wrap the `msg.payload` after the = in `parseInt()`